# how to add a new label every time I click on a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

So I made this code that calculates a student's average and I am trying to get the results to appear at the bottom of the window.
the problem is that I want a new result label to appear every time I click on the "Submit" button.
right now it's only replacing the existing label with the new data.

```
import tkinter as tk

def calculate_status(average): 
    if 0 <= average <= 39:
        return "Failed"  
    elif 40 <= average <= 55:
        return "Passed"  
    elif 56 <= average <= 70:
        return "Great" 
    elif 71 <= average <= 100:
        return "Distinctive" 

def grade(name, grades): 
    average = (sum(grades) / len(grades)) 
    status = calculate_status(average)
    result_label = tk.Label(window, text=f"STUDENT NAME: {name}\nAVERAGE: {average}\nSTATUS: {status}", wraplength=300)
    result_label.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    last_row += 8

def get_grades():
    grade_text = input_grade_entry.get()
    grades = [float(grade) for grade in grade_text.split(",")]
    for grade in grades:
        if not 0 <= grade <= 100:
            input_grade_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            input_grade_entry.insert(0, "Grades must be between 0 and 100 separated by commas.")
            return []
    return grades

def get_student_info():
    global last_row
    name = name_entry.get()
    grades = get_grades()
    if grades:
        grade(name, grades)

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Student Grades")

# Create and place labels and entry widgets
tk.Label(window, text="Student Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
name_entry = tk.Entry(window)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

tk.Label(window, text="Grades (comma-separated):").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
input_grade_entry = tk.Entry(window)
input_grade_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# Create and place the submit button
submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=get_student_info)
submit_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# Initialize last row
last_row = 3

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I don't really know, that's why I came here...

Comment: You put the newly created label at the same position (row 3), so it will overlap the previous one.  Why don't you use the variable `last_row` in `.grid()` inside `grade()`?  Note that you need to declare `last_row` as global variable inside `grade()`.  Also why increasing it by 8?

Comment: Your code runs, but causes errors when used. Please describe what you're doing with the app (what input you enter for example), what you see happening and what you expected to see happening instead.

Comment: Your code is working. Comment out line 18 `#last_row += 8`

Answer (score 0):

Explanation given as and where I've made changes in the code.

```
import tkinter as tk

#Declare a variable count here.
count = 0

def calculate_status(average): 
    if 0 <= average <= 39:
        return "Failed"  
    elif 40 <= average <= 55:
        return "Passed"  
    elif 56 <= average <= 70:
        return "Great" 
    elif 71 <= average <= 100:
        return "Distinctive" 

def grade(name, grades):
    global last_row, count
    average = (sum(grades) / len(grades)) 
    status = calculate_status(average)
    
    # Dont declare a variable name for the label. row value should be multiple of count
    tk.Label(window, text=f"STUDENT NAME: {name}\nAVERAGE: {average}\nSTATUS: {status}", wraplength=300).grid(row=2 + (count*4), columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    last_row += 8

def get_grades():
    grade_text = input_grade_entry.get()
    grades = [float(grade) for grade in grade_text.split(",")]
    for grade in grades:
        if not 0 <= grade <= 100:
            input_grade_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            input_grade_entry.insert(0, "Grades must be between 0 and 100 separated by commas.")
            return []
    return grades

def get_student_info():
    
    # Count every click and make the variable count global

    global last_row, count
    count = count + 1
    name = name_entry.get()
    grades = get_grades()
    if grades:
        grade(name, grades)

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Student Grades")

# Create and place labels and entry widgets
tk.Label(window, text="Student Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
name_entry = tk.Entry(window)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

tk.Label(window, text="Grades (comma-separated):").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
input_grade_entry = tk.Entry(window)
input_grade_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# Create and place the submit button
submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=get_student_info)
submit_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# Initialize last row
last_row = 3

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already created new label for each result, but you put them in the same position (row=3) so newly created label will overlap the previous one.

Suggest to create a frame for the result labels and use `.pack()` on those labels instead:

```py
...
def grade(name, grades):
    average = (sum(grades) / len(grades))
    status = calculate_status(average)
    # create label as child of frame
    result_label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"STUDENT NAME: {name}\nAVERAGE: {average}\nSTATUS: {status}", wraplength=300)
    # simply use .pack()
    result_label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
...

# create a frame for the result labels
frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: But the OP is using grid method for some reasons. The OP would have preferred `grid` over `pack` maybe for some aesthetic preference.