# how to textvariable set with List in entry grid tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I created the tkinter entry grid 5x5 for user feeding how to get and set data in selected entry-box?

```
from tkinter import *
def print_value(entry):
    print( entry.get())
    uservalue[i,j].set('tessting')

root = Tk()
uservalue = []

height = 5
width = 1
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
 entry = Entry(root, textvariable = uservalue[i,j], width=100)  # this line give me error 
        entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
        b = Button(root, text="print value", command= lambda entry=entry: print_value(entry), width=10)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j+1)

mainloop()
```

How to textvariable set with `list[i,j]` for get and set the user input in entry grid

Comment: You are creating a 5x1 grid of entry boxes, not 5x5.  What is the purpose of the button? Should there be only one button per row? Or one button per entry box?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

```py
from tkinter import *

def print_value(row, col):
    print(uservalue[row][col].get())


# def print_value(var):
#   print(var.get())
    

root = Tk()
uservalue = []

height = 5
width = 5
for i in range(height): #Rows
    uservalue.append([])
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        var = StringVar()
        uservalue[i].append(var)
        entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var, width=100)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=j*2)
        # b = Button(root, text="print value", command= lambda var=var: print_value(var), width=10)
        b = Button(root, text="print value", command= lambda row=i, col=j: print_value(row, col), width=10)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j*2+1)

mainloop()
```

- Multidimensional lists (a list containing lists as elements) must be accessed in the form `my_list[x][y]`, not `my_list[x,y]`.
- the `textvariable=` parameter expects an instance of a `tkinter.Variable` or its subclasses (like `tkinter.StringVar`)
- This means you first have to create/instantiate your `StringVar()`
- Then you can add it to the list and use it for your Entry widget

Comment: sir this code ok run without error / please guide me how to add new record and delete selected record by button press / please give me sample code thank you in advance for you your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

Append the StringVars to a 2d list containing rows and column. To get the value use list[row][column].get()

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_val(row, col):
    table[row][col] = entry_vars[row][col].get()

root = tk.Tk()

height = 5
width = 1

# create a sample data

table = [[''] for i in range(height) for j in range(width)]

# List to hold Entry widget variables
entry_vars = []

# Create Entry widgets for each cell
for i in range(height):
    row_vars = []
    for j in range(width):
        var = tk.StringVar()
        var.set(table[i][j])
        entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
        entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event, row=i, col=j: get_val(row, col))
        row_vars.append(var)
    entry_vars.append(row_vars)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you Master for your help now please guide me how add new row and delete selected row by button press / please send me the code thank you again and again for your valuable help

Comment: See one of my answers in the following link. By combining the above answer and the following link, you'll get an idea of how to add new row. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78111359/22577409)

Comment: def delete_row(row, col):    #   how to delete selected row   need code 
    return

def add_row(row, col):  #   how to Add New  row need code 
          return

Comment: line 23, in <module>
    var.set(table[i][j])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @toyotaSupra, Change the line 13 into `table = [[''] for i in range(height) for j in range(width)]`. Thank you. Edited now.

Comment: @SuramuthuR It should be `table = [[""]*width for i in range(height)]`.  Your change will not work if `width` is not one. Your original code works if you swap width and height.

Comment: @acw1668, It works. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/H82CyST)

Comment: I said it does not work if `width` is not one.  You can print out `table` to verify it.

Comment: yes @acw1668, That's why I edited before. Yes, changing width and height also will work.

Comment: I wonder why you said it is ok because I just copy your code and change `width = 1` to `width = 2`, and I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on the line `var.set(table[i][j])` when executing the code.